# currency conversion USD to INR

Tags: php

i want to convert currency from USD to INR, the value in USD retrive from url and i want to convert it in INR according the current rate.
 here is the first code:

```
<?php 
 require_once('currency.php');

 $val=$_GET["val"];

 echo currency($val);

 ?>
```

and the second code is:

```
<?php

function currency($val) {
$amount = $val;

 $url = "http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=$amountUSD=?INR";
 $ch = curl_init();
 $timeout = 0;
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_USERAGENT , "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT  6.1)");
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
 $rawdata = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 $data = explode('"', $rawdata);
 $data = explode(' ', $data['3']);
 $var = $data['0'];
 return round($var,3);
 }

 ?>
```

bytheway am testing this code on 0fees.net, the free hosting site, so is there any problem for that as am trying live USD to INR conversion.

Comment: ANd? Is there a question here?

Comment: it is not working. can any one give me a proper solution?

Comment: check my answer... i have solved this....

Comment: check my comment on my answer.... and one thing more, on your php code have bug that i have solved out...

Answer (score 2):

The error lies in the following code:

```
function currency($val) {
    $amount = $val;
    $url = "http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=$amountUSD=?INR";
    // ...                                              ^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

php tries to evaluate the variable `$amountUSD` (according to php's [string parsing rules](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing)) and fails with a notice:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: amountUSD in usdtoinr.php code on line 3
```

Instead, you should write:

```
function currency($val) {
    $amount = floatval($val);
    $url = 'http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=' . $amount . 'USD=?INR';
    // ...
}
```

To catch these errors in the future, make sure to set [`error_reporting`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) to `E_ALL | E_STRICT` on your development machine.

Also, the result of google's query is a JSON document. Since the order of properties in the objects may vary, you must use a proper JSON parser such as [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to parse it, like this:

```
$data = json_decode($rawdata, true);
$tmp = explode(' ', $data['rhs']);
return floatval($tmp[0]);
```

In general, it is also a good idea to include a hint to your actual user agent (for example the homepage of your software) in the user agent.

Comment: Also check out json_decode to parse the data returned by Google, should be more reliable than the first explode().

Comment: Thanks, didn't spot that. Updated the answer.

Comment: am a novice in this field, can u please edit this one for exact changes?

Comment: @dhruba Sorry, stackoverflow is not a [send teh codez](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/plz-email-me-teh-codez.aspx) gig. If you want someone to do your whole programming for you, you should just hire an experienced programmer.

Comment: no i did't mean dat, i just want to know the format of json_decode as u told earlier.

Comment: @dhruba I updated the answer with an example of how to use `json_decode`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this PHP code

```
<?php

function currency($from_Currency,$to_Currency,$amount) {
$amount = urlencode($amount);
$from_Currency = urlencode($from_Currency);
$to_Currency = urlencode($to_Currency);
$url = "http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=$amount$from_Currency=?$to_Currency";
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 0;
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_USERAGENT , "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$rawdata = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$data = explode('"', $rawdata);
$data = explode('"', $data['3']);
$var = $data[0];
return round($var,3);
}

?>
```

and Use this for output, when you enter any amount it will be converted from USD to INR

```
<?php 
 require_once('currency.php');

  $amount=@$_GET["val"];

$from='USD';

$to='INR';

 echo currency($from,$to,$amount);

 ?>

<form method="get" ><input name="val" type="text"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>
```

Comment: you mean you are running this on free hosting, so bro some of free hosting curl not enabled... thats y we don't use curl, you have to use any hosting with curl enabled... i am using 000webhost.com but not sure is curl supported or not.... let me found and will let you know...

Comment: yes you can use it on http://000webhost.com i have upload it you can check on my free hosting.... http://amughal4u.co.cc/currency/